# How can I run multiple versions of my application against the same database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

**Backround**: I have multiple versions of my application running in my production environment. Depending on the user account that's used, the user will have access to a different version of the software.

**Environment**: Currently SQL Server 2005, imminently migrating to SQL Server 2008, ASP.Net

**Problem**: Each version of the software may or may not use different versions of the stored procedures that interact with the data in the database. Currently when a version is changed, whoever changes it creates a new copy and appends an incremental version number to the end. At this point we have numerous versions of some stored procs and only one version of others and nobody is sure which version of the application is pointing to which version of the stored procs - it's a mess.

I'm looking for a solution that will neatly package the stored procs up for any given version of the application to be used as the basis for a new version. This means that the new version of the application can be pointed to the new set of procs which can be rewritten or modified to the end user's content without affecting other versions of the applications that are currently available in production.

I originally thought about schemas, but one part of the issue is that the procs are heavily coupled with other procs and user defined functions, so when copying to another schema, we'd new to map and replace all these links which isn't ideal.

It seems like this is a problem that should already be solved, but I don't know what I'm looking for in order to find a viable solution.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Step 1: Eliminate stored procedures...they are evil and hard to deal with (as you've found out)

Comment: @cdeszaq Sadly, they're a fact of life for any application developer that writes applications reliant on a database. Getting rid of them is not an option. In fact, I've never come across an enterprise environment where *not* having them *is* an option.

Comment: If you are having to change the stored procedures, then you have _way_ too much coupling between the application and the database. The database should not have _any_ notion of what the applications that use it need in terms of logic. If you _do_ need a central data access manager, then wrap the DB up in a service and rely on that. A service is at least a manageable (aka versionable) application. A database is _not_.

Comment: do the version numbers tacked on the stored proc names describe that particular stored proc's version or the version of the application that drove the modification in the stored proc?

Comment: @hatchet Until now (before I got my hands on it), the version is the version of the stored proc, not the version of the application. I'm thinking it should become the version of the application. But even that's not tidy enough for my liking. I'd like not to keep having version numbers on the proc names at all.

Comment: how many concurrent application versions typically exist in production at any one time?

Comment: @hatchet Currently there are 2, but there could be any number. Going forward there may be more than 2, but that number has not been defined.

Answer (score 1):

Given the mess you describe, if you must stick with stored procs, I would be inclined to have only one copy of each stored proc, but have all stored procs take versionNumber as the final parameter. Then each stored proc has one name, and any version specific code is there in the context of the stored proc it relates to. Stored procs that have no version specific code just ignore that versionNumber paremter (but still have it in their signature).

One of the big problems I see in your current situation is that if there are 4 nearly identical versions of a stored proc, and someone fixes a bug in one of them, it is too easy to forget to make the identical fix in all the other versions. The solution I described would at least reduce the amount of duplicate code, and reduce the chance of bug fixes only fixing one version of the stored proc.

In this situation though, I would also feel a strong urge to get application version specific logic out of the database and into the codebase, and leave in the database that logic that is data specific but application agnostic.

Comment: Except that it destroys some of the benefits of stored procs, which is compilation.  Having state flags that completely change the functionality of a procedure will cause all sorts of compilation issues.  You will end up with horribly bad plans being cached, unless he marks each sproc for recompile.  You generally shouldn't do this, and if you do, you should have your sproc that takes a version number, call other sprocs, so you at least gain the benefits from their compilation.

Comment: Over time, old versions are retired, so if a bug is found, it would be fixed in the newer versions, but may not be fixed in the old versions. It may be, that's not really my call. All I need to do is provide a real viable mechanism that the DBA team would approve that will get this mess under control.

Comment: @BenAlabaster - I think if you described the typical nature of the differences between one version of a stored proc and another, even give an example, it might help those offering solutions.

Comment: @BrianRudolph - I agree with what you're saying. Depending on the version differences though, the argument doesn't necessarily need to be used in a performance harming way. And having multiple nearly identical versions of stored procs is less than ideal as well, although in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are no backwards-incompatible schema and data changes between versions, I would move *all* of the application logic into the application code. Once you have that, then you can use the wealth of existing versioning technologies to deploy multiple versions of the application that all point at the same database.

Trying to version store procedures is, in many cases, a fruitless effort because there simply isn't the needed access to the code in *most* RDBMSystems. In general, stored procedures are considered to be a potentially good idea than just didn't pan out.

Comment: I'd like to dispute this response. Stored procs are used for a world more than just "application logic". They're used to provide an underlying layer that transforms the data stored in the database into a form that's valid for application or applications that are using it. There is no option to move stored proc/function logic into the application. None of the logic is relevant to the application. Any logic that *is* relevant to the application is already there. Not to mention the security and performance implications of this approach.

Comment: My comment above on the question addresses the data transform parts. I agree that stored procedures _do_ have their uses (data integrity being one of them), but I stand by my point that anything requiring changing along with an application (especially for different versions of an application) should happen at a layer _above_ the database. Perhaps not all the way in the application, but definitely not _within_ the database itself.